aws lambda / api gateway multiple calls 503
I am using AWS Lambda Functions as a REST API to call some other REST API as well as get data from DynamoDB. However, when my website loads and sends multiple get requests to the API Gateway, which forwards it to the lambda functions, I often get 503 "Service Unavailable" responses. It seems to be random which call fails exactly.
Do I already have to add some kind of load balancing? I actually didn't expect having to do this so early. It's about 10 calls and 3-4 different lambda functions.

You need to enable API Gateway logging: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html and then look at the logs for one of these errors to see what the actual issue is. And also check your Lambda function's logs for any errors.

Sounds like you might be running into cold starts.
The first time you hit a lambda it has to spin up the container to run the service.
This repo helps keep lambda warm;
https://github.com/jeremydaly/lambda-warmer
How to ping your lambda to keep it warm (from the repo README.md);

Don’t ping more often than every 5 minutes Invoke the function directly (i.e. don’t use API Gateway to invoke it)
Pass in a test payload that can be identified as such
Create handler logic that replies accordingly without running the whole function

